# User State Migration Tool - Does this create the profile on the machine?

Tags: user-profile, mdt-2013, usmt

I am on a domain without roaming profiles.  We are looking at possibly implementing the User Stat Migration Tool with our MDT server, but I have a few questions first.
Using the USMT, can you effectively create a profile on a new machine without logging in as that user?  Or do I need to log in as the user and then run USMT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does actually create a profile for the user!  I tested it on a machine and had the user log in, sure enough it didn't create another user profile folder or anything

Answer (score 2):

As you figured out; yes.  It will create the C:\Users\%username% directory of all of the users that were backed up.

One thing noteworthy is that it also applies the previous local group memberships.  If the user was a local admin, they'll be a local admin on the new machine.  So, if you're hoping that a side benefit of re-imaging is to clean up rogue local admins, think again.  I'm sure you could adjust USMT to change that behavior though.

Comment: Yeah, we have other methods for cleaning up rogue local admins.  USMT is pretty useful for copying a profile, it even gets the ODBC connections of the system and user.